# ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string when I am trying to use trunc with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

My title basically says my issue. I am typing the following into Oracle:

```
SELECT FName, Lname, TRUNC(months_between(sysdate,Bdate)/12) year

FROM EMPLYEE, works, assign

WHERE SSN = ESSN AND PNO = Pnumber AND Pname LIKE 'P%';
```

When I type that I just get ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string. I am trying to have it show the names and age of the employees working on projects beginning with P. BDATE is the date of birth from emplyee table. Its format is Year-Month-Date.

Comment: What is `Bdate` ?

Comment: @Guru Bdate is coming from emplyee table. It is identifying the employees date of birth. I am trying to get current date and have it calculate the emplyees age

Comment: @gravity00 What is the format of Bdate?

Comment: The `months_between()` function does work as expected. However, if it gets wrong data it might get error. Are you in 12c?

Comment: @NaveenArora Bdate format is Year-Month-Date

Comment: @Guru oracle9i if thats what you are asking

Comment: :( Oracle 9i. Hmmmm. Not sure, but at this moment you need to ensure your data date format is correct. If you are in 12c you could be using `validate_conversion` function.

Comment: @gravity00  What is data type of Bdate?

Comment: @NaveenArora It is VarChar(100) does it need to be something else?

Comment: @gravity00 Thats the issue. you will have to convert it to date. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to convert data type of Bdate to `Date`:

```
SELECT FName, Lname, TRUNC(months_between(sysdate,to_date(Bdate,'YYYY-MM-DD'))/12) year

FROM EMPLYEE, works, assign

WHERE SSN = ESSN AND PNO = Pnumber AND Pname LIKE 'P%';
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer and help. That was my issue. I needed to convert bdate to date for it to work. I appreciate the help and I gave you the answer.

Comment: ^1.. This should work, you need to convert the string to date using to_date()

Answer (score 0):

The `months_between()` function expects two dates. When two dates are provided, it returns months between with floating points up to several decimal places.

However, the "ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string" means, one of the dates is not a correct formatted date.

For DBs from 12c, you could use: `validate_conversion()` function to ensure the date format works.

Assuming, `BDATE` is just a string.

```
SELECT CASE validate_conversion(BDATE as date) 
WHEN 1 THEN trunc(months_between(sysdate, TO_DATE(BDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))/12)
WHEN 0 THEN 0
END "YEARS"
FROM EMPLYEE, works, assign
WHERE SSN = ESSN AND PNO = Pnumber AND Pname LIKE 'P%';
```